# Javascript редактирование стиля строки таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая таблица.

```
<form class="regular" method="post" action="" id="ask">
    <table><tr>
      <td class="field-name">
       Ваше Имя&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></td>
      <td class="field-input">
       <input type="text" name="name" class="form-text-input" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field-name">
        Индекс</td>
      <td class="field-input">
       <input type="text" name="index_id" class="form-text-input" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field-name">
        Город</td>
      <td class="field-input">
       <input type="text" name="city" class="form-text-input" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field-name">
        Ваш отзыв&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></td>
      <td class="field-input">
       <textarea style="height: 100px" id="textarea_review" name="review"         class="form-textarea"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field-name">
        Email</td>
      <td class="field-input">
       <input type="text" name="email" class="form-text-input" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field-name">
         Защита от спама&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></td>
      <td class="field-input">
         <img src="/extra/captcha-simple/" alt="" />
         <input type="text" name="captcha" class="form-text-input" value="" />
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table><p><span class="required">*</span>Обязательные для заполнения поля.</p><div class="form-buttons"><input value="Оставить отзыв" type="submit"/></div>          </form>
```

Не знаю убрать/добавить стиль display:none  для второй строки таблицы.

```
    <tr>
      <td class="field-name">
        Индекс</td>
      <td class="field-input">
       <input type="text" name="index_id" class="form-text-input" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Могу только убрать поле

```
document.getElementsByName('index_id')[0].style.display="none";
```

Таблица создается динамически - добавить id нет возможности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете добраться до нужного ряда таблицы без id

```
document.getElementById('ask').getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].style.display="none";
```

[вот тут индекс скрывается](https://jsfiddle.net/wnLk1gyg/)